# Best method to calculate provision from a table with provision levels?

Tags: excel

I have a table with provision levels.

```
Sales   Provision
0       5%
20 000  22%
100 000 30%
```

A salesman has 5% provision on the first 20 000, 22% on the next 80 000 and 30% on everything above that.

For example a salesman who sells for 230 000 will have provision

```
=20 000 * 0,05 + 80 000 * 0,22 + 130 000 * 0,30
```

How can I express this efficiently with a formula? The formula

- Needs to be easy to copy to several rows (where a salesman is described by each row)
- Needs to work even if I add more provision levels

Comment: I'm thinking there might be a formula that would work even if I add a fourth provision level, and a fifth one.

Answer (score 1):

Well I can say this works (hopefully) for requirement #2:

> Needs to work even if I add more provision levels

But note that I am unsure about requirement #1:

> Needs to be easy to copy to several rows (where a salesman is described by each row)

Anyway, with this data:

```
   A     B      C           D          E
------------------------------------------
0       0.05        Value           230000
20000   0.22        Total Provision  57600
100000  0.3
```

I used this formula in E2:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("A2:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1))-INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1)-1))*INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1)-1))+(E1-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E1,A:A,1)))*INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E1,A:A,1)),E1*B1)
```

If we break this formula down:

The first basic step is to find the index at which the sale value resides.  This is the first lower value compared to the sale value. In your example data this is straight forward because the index is the last in the provision list. However to accommodate sale values that fall within the list range we can use:

```
MATCH(E1,A:A,1)
```

where E1 is the sale value and A:A is the sale-provision list.

Using this we can incorporate an `INDIRECT` to get the desired range we need to work with.  In this case `A1 to A & Index`:

```
INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1))
```

But even within this range we need to figure out two distinct values:

- The provision value index lower than our sale value (i.e. `20 000 * 0.05 + 80 000 * 0.22`)
- The rest of the provision sale value (i.e. `130 000 * 0.30`)

So to get the first value we need to set up an array like this:

```
(20000   -     0) * 0.05  =  20000*.05 =  1000
(100000  - 20000) * 0.22  =  80000*.22 = 17600
                                   SUM = 18600
```

That can be done by using

```
(A2:A3 - A1:A2)*(B1:B2)
```

But to put that in our `INDIRECT` formula, that would look like

```
INDIRECT("A2:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1))     <- A2:A3
INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1)-1)   <- A1:A2
INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1)-1)   <- B1:B2

(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1))-INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1)-1))*INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1)-1))
```

Just surround that with a `SUMPRODUCT` to get the total:

```
SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("A2:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1))-INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1)-1))*INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH(E1,A:A,1)-1))
```

Then the second value is just the total sale value subtracted by our index value and multiplied by the corresponding provision rate.  So that would be:

```
(E1-A3)*B3
```

We actually don't need `INDIRECT` here, a couple `INDEX - MATCH` lookups will do:

```
E1                          <- E1
INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E1,A:A,1))  <- A3
INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E1,A:A,1))  <- B3

(E1-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E1,A:A,1)))*INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E1,A:A,1))
```

Then adding those to formulas together results in the derived formula I showed earlier.

The final addition however was to add an `IFERROR` wrapper because if the value is less than the first non-zero provision the `INDEX-MATCH` and `INDIRECT` will fail.  So in the case of an error that means we just need to multiply the sale value by the first provision rate:

```
E1*B1
```

And of course if you add an additional provision row:

```
   A     B      C          D          E
------------------------------------------
0       0.05        Value           230000
20000   0.22        Total Provision  63600
100000  0.30
200000  0.50
```

Or change the provision:

```
   A     B      C          D          E
------------------------------------------
0       0.05        Value            22000
20000   0.22        Total Provision   1440
100000  0.30
```

The formula will index to the proper provision and calculate it properly.

Also,

Since I know I use commas and decimals in my locale and I realized you don't here is the formula for semi-colon list separator:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("A2:A"&MATCH(E1;A:A;1))-INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH(E1;A:A;1)-1))*INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH(E1;A:A;1)-1))+(E1-INDEX(A:A;MATCH(E1;A:A;1)))*INDEX(B:B;MATCH(E1;A:A;1));E1*B1)
```